# Mathematical Typesetting not Proper in Rmarkdown HTML output, but now it suddenly is?

Tags: html, output, r-markdown, mathematical-typesetting

I have been looking for a while now, and have been trying some things here and there, but I just cannot seem to find the solution to the problem of *mathematical typesetting not being properly displayed in Rmarkdown's HTML output*. That definitive guide for Rmarkdown does not seem to mention anything that helps, and online there is just no clear answer to me either. All this searching and fiddling takes too much time.

For example, as suggested by someone, I reloaded the page, but it did not work. Not knowing exactly how to go about the issue, I probably compiled the code (or knitted, or whatever you'd call it), as if it were LaTeX, but it did not work. There were a few other things I tried, but I already forgot about them.

**MAIN DESCRIPTION**

Essentially, whenever I have some mathematical code, using `$` or `$$`, the *raw code* instead of the desired mathematical typesetting is displayed in the HTML file.

**SUDDEN GOOD RESULT?**
But now, as I just opened the HTML file again to see what would happen, the typesetting is correct? The only difference I can think of, in this case, is that I was online. What would that have to do with it, if at all?

**SOLUTION**
In any case, seeing all this, what is the next thing to do, to actually get it solved quickly? I want to have the option to send the resultant HTML file to anyone, and there should not be any need to be online.

Comment: Hi @Lee Taylor. May I ask what exactly was edited concerning the post? If I know, and if indeed in error, then I know better for the next time.

Comment: If you click on "edited yesterday" above, you will see the edit history. Although you can make your headings super-large, it kind of smacks of "look at my post!!!!!!!", hence the edit.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. Heh heh, yeah, it might give that impression to some, though I would say to them that I merely chose on the basis of quickness and ease of ###, and because it was the smallest of the usually available direct headings (as far as I knew). It would have been too bad indeed, if someone were to think what you have rightly tried to avoid.